# win api - TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT and InvalidateRect

Tags: winapi

I have seen the following TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT event handling:

```
RECT rect={0};
TreeView_GetItemRect(hwnd, hitem, &rect, FALSE);
InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, TRUE);
```

Editing a tree view label without the above code works fine. Is it redundant or there may be a situation where such handling is necessary ?

Comment: Yes, there is no obvious reason for this code.  Don't trust the rest of it too much either.

Comment: It depends what else the code does. Are they doing custom drawing which changes when the listview has focus, for example?

Comment: @jon: Even in that case, the system generates the notifications by the time input focus moves into the overlay edit control. Regardless of whether the code uses the standard, treeview-created edit control, a manually created edit control, or some other custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-beginlabeledit#remarks) of the `TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` contains hints about a treeview control's internals:

> When label editing begins, an edit control is created [...]

By default, that edit control is positioned and sized to cover the item that is to be edited. There is no immediately obvious reason to invalidate an area that's going to be covered by another control right away.

It doesn't even make sense to invalidate the area covered by the item, if the implementation chooses to provide a custom size and position for the edit control. By the time the `WM_PAINT` message gets handled, the treeview control still holds the initial value for that item, so parts not covered by the edit control merely get redrawn as they were.